# flake8: import statements are in the wrong order

Tags: python, sublimetext3, flake8

PEP8 suggests that:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

I am using [Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint) which Sublime Text plugin for lint Python files.

My code as below:

```
import logging
import re
import time
import urllib
import urlparse

from flask import Blueprint
from flask import redirect
from flask import request
from flask.ext.login import current_user
from flask.ext.login import login_required

from my_application import one_module
```

it will show the warning as below:

> `import statements are in the wrong order, from my_application should be before from from flask.ext.login`

but flask is the third party library, it should before my `my_application` import. This is why? How to fix it?

Comment: I suppose it's because of „library specific imports” - probably Flake8Link understand that flask.ext.login is specific for library. I'd say - ignore flake8 error.

Comment: According to [Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint) the import order checks are off unless you specify them. Further, it's using [flake8-import-order](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-import-order#configuration) which let's you tell it what your application name is so it knows what is a local import.

Comment: At the end of the day, *it really doesn't matter*. As long as your imports are grouped in a reasonable manner **to you** and the people that will be reading your code after you, don't worry about whether an automated checker thinks module a should be imported before or after module b.

Answer (score 12):

The flake8-import-order plugin needs to be [configured](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-import-order#configuration) to know which names should be considered local to your application.

For your example, if using a `.flake8` ini file in your package root directory, it should contain:

```
[flake8]
application_import_names = my_application
```

Alternatively you can use only relative imports for application local imports:

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import sys

import requests

from . import (
    client
)


...
```